# Why is $\operatorname{arccot} x$ not $\arctan \frac{1}{x}$ when $x<0$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

$\operatorname{arccsc}(x) = \arcsin \frac{1}{x}$ , and $\operatorname{arcsec}(x) = \arccos \frac{1}{x}$.

Why doesn't $\operatorname{arccot}(\cdot)$ behave the same..?

[image]

Comment: This is because $arccot(x)$ is defined to have range $(0,\pi)$ while $arctan(x)$ is defined to have range $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$

Comment: @AlanAbraham Why are you answering in a comment?

Comment: @Arthur I felt it was too short to be an answer. Also I thought it would be better if someone elaborated on the purpose for why these functions have different ranges. I don't know the reasons, so I didn't think my response was a complete answer.

Comment: @AlanAbraham That’s *a* definition of arccotangent, but [this definition](https://dlmf.nist.gov/4.23) defines $arccot(x)$ as $arctan(\frac{1}{x})$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is just a matter of convention. Refer to [these illustrations](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xcw5fy4dnw) as you read the following:

1. [Wolfpham
   Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=domain+and+range+of++arccot+%28x%29)
   and many (most?) texts **define** $\mathrm{arccot}(x)$ over the
   domain $\mathbb R$ by inverting the discontinuous
   $\left(-\frac{\pi}2,0\right)\cup\left(0,\frac{\pi}2\right]$ section
   of $\cot(x).$ Consequently, $$\mathrm{arccot}(x)=\begin{cases}  
   \arctan\left(\frac1x\right) &\text{ when }x\neq0;\\   \frac {\pi}2
   &\text{ when }x=0, \end{cases}$$ and has range
   $$\left(-\frac{\pi}2,0\right)\cup\left(0,\frac{\pi}2\right].$$
2. On the other hand, Desmos **defines** $\mathrm{arccot}(x)$ over the
   domain $\mathbb R$ by inverting the continuous $(0,\pi)$ section of
   $\cot(x).$
   ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values)
   says that this is the usual definition.) Consequently,
   $$\mathrm{arccot}(x)=\begin{cases}   \arctan\left(\frac1x\right)+\pi
   &\text{ when }x<0;\\   \frac {\pi}2 &\text{ when }x=0;\\  
   \arctan\left(\frac1x\right) &\text{ when }x>0, \end{cases}$$ and has
   range $$\large\left(0,\pi\right).$$

---

[Jean-Claude](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4226298/why-is-operatornamearccot-x-not-arctan-frac1x-when-x0/4226428#comment8777901_4226428) points out that while the first definition above gives $$\mathrm{arccot}(x)=\begin{cases}
  -\frac {\pi}2-\arctan(x) &\text{ when }x<0;\\
  \frac {\pi}2-\arctan(x) &\text{ when }x\geq0,
\end{cases}$$ the second definition has $\mathrm{arccot}$ and $\arctan$ as [reflections of each other](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hc7m1ojliq) in the line $y=\frac{\pi}4$, so<sup>҂</sup> gives the friendlier $$\mathrm{arccot}(x)=\frac {\pi}2-\arctan(x)\quad\text{ on }\mathbb R.$$

All things considered $\big($clean relationship with $\arctan\left(\frac1x\right),$ range centred about $0$   versus   clean relationship with $\arctan(x),$ continuous$\big),$ I prefer the second definition to the first.

<sup>҂</sup>An analytical argument (based on the second definition) is this:
$\quad\arctan(x)$ and $\mathrm{arccot}(x)$ are both continuous on $\mathbb R,$ so $$\arctan(x)+\mathrm{arccot}(x)$$—which has derivative $0$ on $\mathbb R$ and value $(\frac{\pi}4+\frac{\pi}4=\frac{\pi}2)$ at $(x=1)$—is also continuous on $\mathbb R.$ As such, this sum identically equals $\frac{\pi}2.$

Comment: +1, but I prefer the continuous one. After all, $\mathrm{arccos}$' range isn't centered either and it's not a problem. And $\mathrm{arccot}\, x$ has a clean relatioship with $\arctan x$. Anyway, it's only a matter of taste, and as long as it's defined somewhere when it's used, there is no problem.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Your argument is compelling and I've switched sides!

Comment: I'm late to this party, but I see I already chose the right side.

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on Alan's comment:

Since the functions $\tan$ and $\cot$ have period $\pi$, given a real number $x\in\mathbb R$, there is no "correct" way to choose its inverse $\arctan(x)$ or $\operatorname{arccot}(x)$. For instance, $\arctan(0)$ could be $0$, or $\pi$, or any other multiple of $\pi$.

However, let us now choose an (arbitrary) value for $\arctan(0)$, say $0$. Then, there is only one way to define $\arctan$ while having it be *continuous*. This choice makes the range of $\arctan$ be $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, which is exactly the interval Alan mentioned.

Similarly, we usually choose $\operatorname{arccot}(0)=\pi/2$ and let it be continuous. This defines $\operatorname{arccot}$ uniquely, and makes its range $(0,\pi)$.

---

The above explains how the definitions of $\arctan(x)$ and $\operatorname{arccot}(x)$ came to be. Now, why does this weird discontinuity exist?

This is because we are considering $\arctan(1/x)$, and $1/x$ is discontinuous at $x=0$. Thus, it makes sense that there is a discontinuous "jump" at $x=0$.