# Sometimes correct answer does not come while solving inverse trigonometric equations?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

**I have a trigonometric equation in which we have to find the values of x.**
Here is the solution which i have done, but the answer is x ∈ (0,1).
Why it is that sometimes when we solve inverse trigonometric equations , the answer does not match with the original answer and we have to always check by putting our values of x in the given equation to verify, even if we have done each and every step properly? [please see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9brc.jpg):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a simple range issue. For negative $x$, the left hand side of the original equation is greater than $\pi$. The range of inverse cotangent only goes up to $\pi$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

$$2\arccos(x)=\mathrm{arccot}\left(\frac{2x^2-1}{2x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)$$

The immediate implicit restrictions:

- $x\neq0$
- $1-x^2>0,\;$ i.e., $\;x\in(-1,1)$
- the left-side principal domain and principal range are $[-1,1]$ and $[0,2\pi],$ respectively.

So, $\,x\in(-1,0)\cup(0,1).$

So, $$-1<2x^2-1<1$$ and $$-2<2x\sqrt{1-x^2}<2;$$ so, $$\frac{2x^2-1}{2x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\in\mathbb R;$$ so, the right-side principal domain is $\mathbb R;$ so, [the right-side principal range](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4226428/21813) is $(0,\pi).$

So, the left-side effective (restricted) range is $(0,\pi);$ so the left-side effective (restricted) domain is $(0,1).$

Hence, the solution set must be a subset of $$(0,1).$$