# Is this statement about inverse $\cot$ valid to write?

Tags: trigonometry

I was curious if one can bring the negative sign out as we do in case of $\sin^{-1}(x)$, $\tan^{-1}(x)$, & $\csc^{-1}(x)$. Can one do the same for $\cos^{-1}(x)$, $\sec^{-1}(x)$, & $\cot^{-1}(x)$? For example,

$$\cot^{-1}(-\tan(x))$$

$$=-\cot^{-1}(\tan(x))...(i)$$

Can I write (i)? I'm asking this because if $x=45^{\circ}\text{(any acute angle)}$,

$$\cot^{-1}(-\tan(45^{\circ}))$$

$$=-\cot^{-1}(\tan(45^{\circ}))$$

$$=-\cot^{-1}(1)$$

$$=-45^{\circ}$$

Now, $-45^{\circ}$ is outside the restricted range of $\cot^{-1}(x)$:$(0,\pi)$. So, is (i) valid to write?

Comment: Here is a graph of what is going on: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lazt9xwoks

Comment: "outside the restricted range" ... I think you have answered your own question already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends: step (i) is valid if and only if you use the first instead of the second definition of $\textrm{arccot}$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4226428/21813). This is because $\textrm{arccot}$ is an [odd function](https://www.shsu.edu/%7Ekws006/Precalculus/1.4_Function_Symmetries_files/1.4%20FunctionSymmetries%20slides%204to1.pdf) only in the first definition.

1. [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arccot+%28-tan%28pi%5C4%29%29) uses the first definition, so it does give the answer that you suggested, $-45^\circ.$
2. [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zcpqs4y31s) uses the second definition (which is my preference), so it instead gives $135^\circ.$ The link shared by Henry in the above comments, as well as José's answer, corresponds to this.

P.S. On the other hand, it *is* always valid to write $$\arctan(-x)=-\arctan (x).$$

Answer (score 3):

The equality $(i)$ is not correct. Since $\operatorname{arccot}$ is the inverse of the restriction of $\cot$ to $(0,\pi)$, it is a function from $\Bbb R$ into $(0,\pi)$ and therefore it cannot possibly be an odd function.  In fact, if $x\in\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)$, then $\operatorname{arccot}\bigl(\tan(x)\bigr)=x+\frac\pi2$.