# What is the sum of arcus cotangents?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inverse-function

Say I wish to find the sum of three arcus cotangents. I wanted to start with a smaller example, say
$$\mathrm{arccot}{x} + \mathrm{arccot}{y}.$$

I know that
$$
\mathrm{arccot}{x} = 
\begin{cases} 
\arctan{\frac{1}{x}} & \text{if $x>0$} \\
\pi + \arctan{\frac{1}{x}} & \text{if $x<0$}
\end{cases}
$$

And that
$$
\arctan(x)+\arctan(y) = \begin{cases}\arctan\left(\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy}\right), &xy < 1 \\
\pi + \arctan\left(\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy}\right), &x>0,\; y>0,\; xy>1 \\
-\pi + \arctan\left(\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy}\right), &x<0,\; y<0,\; xy > 1\end{cases}
$$

Is this the right path to find the expression for $\mathrm{arccot}{x} + \mathrm{arccot}{y}$?

Simply consider every case of $x,y,xy$? How to get to the sum of three arcus cotangents from here?

Was also looking for a "ready" formulation online but I ultimately failed. So out of curiosity - are arcus cotangents that rarely used?

Comment: Read here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326334/a-question-about-the-arctangent-addition-formula

Comment: Well as you can see in my post, I am looking for the expression for $\mathrm{arccot}{x} + \mathrm{arccot}{y}$. In the other post that you forwarded, the question, as well as the answer, was about the sum of arcus tangents and the intuition behind this expression.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't read the post properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that  $$ \mathrm{arccot}(x) =  \begin{cases} 
> \arctan{\frac{1}{x}} & \text{if $x>0$} \\ \pi + \arctan{\frac{1}{x}} &
> \text{if $x<0$} \end{cases} $$

And a small addition: $$=\frac\pi2\quad\text{if }x=0.$$

Based on this definition (there are two common definitions of arccot), we have [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4226428/21813) on $\mathbb R,$ $$\arctan(x)\equiv\frac {\pi}2-\mathrm{arccot}(x).$$

> and that $$\arctan(x)+\arctan(y) = \begin{cases}\arctan\left(\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy}\right), &xy < 1 \\
> \pi + \arctan\left(\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy}\right), &x>0,\; y>0,\; xy>1 \\
> -\pi + \arctan\left(\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy}\right), &x<0,\; y<0,\; xy > 1\end{cases}$$
>
> Is this the right path to find the expression for $\mathrm{arccot }(x) + \mathrm{arccot }(y)$?

Substituting in the above identity and noting that $\arctan$ is an odd function: $$\mathrm{arccot }(x)+\mathrm{arccot }(y) = \begin{cases}\pi+\arctan\left(\dfrac{x+y}{xy-1}\right), &xy < 1 \\
\arctan\left(\dfrac{x+y}{xy-1}\right), &x>0,\; y>0,\; xy>1 \\
2\pi + \arctan\left(\dfrac{x+y}{xy-1}\right), &x<0,\; y<0,\; xy > 1.\end{cases}$$

Comment: Makes sense! Forgot about the $\arctan(x)\equiv\frac {\pi}2-\mathrm{arccot}(x)$ bit.

Comment: @bajun65537 To be fair, this identity isn't that well-known; it is [false](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arctan%28x%29+%2B++arccot+%28x%29+%3D+pi%2F2) (or rather, it is true only for $x=0$) when using Wolfram Alpha's definition of arccot, which is different from ours.

Comment: Hmm and could you clarify why we can write it this way? I mean why on the right-hand side we can have PLUS arctan instead of MINUS? At first, I just thought it does not make any difference but now I'm not so sure.

Comment: @bajun65537 1. I've added an elaboration; in case it isnt sufficiently clear: an odd function $f$ is a function such that $f(-x)=-f(x).$   2. Use [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zntuwokcxp) to check our derived identity.