# Why cannot we find a constant for function $f(x) = \operatorname{arccot} x - \arctan\frac{1}{x}$ even though its derivative is $0$?

Tags: derivatives

I came across this exercise from Apostol book Volume 1 Ex 6.22 Q11.

The function $f(x) =  \operatorname{arccot} x - \arctan\frac{1}{x}$ has derivative $0$ when $x\neq 0$. But in the meantime, we cannot find a constant number $C$ such that $f(x) = C$.

I am interested to know what is happening here.

Comment: What is $f(1)$ versus $f(-1)$?

Comment: What would you say about the function $f(x) = \frac{|x|}{x}$ when $x \ne 0$?

Answer (score 2):

There are two commonly-used definitions of $\mathrm{arccot}:$

1. $$\mathrm{arccot}(x)=\begin{cases}  
       \arctan\left(\frac1x\right) &\text{ when }x\neq0;\\   \frac {\pi}2
       &\text{ when }x=0. \end{cases}$$

   With Definition 1, $f(x)$ is indeed identically zero for nonzero $x.$

   [image]
2. $$\mathrm{arccot}(x)=\begin{cases}   \arctan\left(\frac1x\right)+\pi
   &\text{ when }x<0;\\   \frac {\pi}2 &\text{ when }x=0;\\  
   \arctan\left(\frac1x\right) &\text{ when }x>0. \end{cases}$$

   If Apostle is using Definition 2, then what's going on is this:

   [image]

   Even though the **Zero Derivative Theorem** says that $$f'(x)=0\implies f(x)=C,$$ this is with reference to $f$ being continuous on the interval in question. Since $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$ isn't an interval, the theorem is inapplicable.

Comment: I actually never saw the first definition before, interesting! I believe most commonly it is just defined as the inverse of $\cot$ on the domain $(0,π)$.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arccot+x+-+arctan+1%2Fx), Mathematica & Matlab (some of this may have changed) use the first definition! [I prefer the second](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4226428/21813).